# suchThat usages in ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm learning scala by reading the code from ScalaCheck and find many combinators are suffixed by `suchThat`. However, in many cases suchThat doesn't look quite necessary. I'm wondering why they are designed in this way. Here's some excerpted from [GitHub](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala):

```
Example 1.

/** Picks a random value from a list */
def oneOf[T](xs: Seq[T]): Gen[T] =
    choose(0, xs.size-1).map(xs(_)).suchThat(xs.contains)
```

`map` picks an element from xs and therefore `xs.contains` seems redundant.

--

```
Example 2.

def containerOfN[C[_],T](n: Int, g: Gen[T])
    (implicit evb: Buildable[T,C], evt: C[T] => Traversable[T]): Gen[C[T]] =
    sequence[C,T](Traversable.fill(n)(g)) suchThat { c =>
      c.size == n && c.forall(g.sieveCopy)
    }
```

Why is `c.size == n` needed, given that a successful `sequence` would return in the length of n?

--

```
Example 3.

/** Generates a string of alpha characters */
def alphaStr: Gen[String] =
    listOf(alphaChar).map(_.mkString).suchThat(_.forall(_.isLetter))
```

Generated strings would consist of list of `alphaChar` which is chosen from uppercase and lowercase letters. Why do we need a `suchThat` to check isLetter again?

--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/commit/2d92eb61a89a8ec2e16d0af8599f9baafc9b5418

Basically, this is needed for the ScalaCheck test case simplification to know what bounds the generated values originally had.